# Can 2 entities have 2 relationships between them at the same time? (JPA)

Tags: java, jpa

For example, I have an account entity with two constructors.

```
@Entity
public class DefaultAccount implements Account {

    @OneToOne(targetEntity = DefaultManager.class)
    private Manager manager;

    public DefaultAccount(String email, String password) {
       this.email = email;
       this.password = password;
    }

    public DefaultAccount(String email, String password, Manager manager) {
       this(email, password);
       this.manager = manager;
    }
    // Getters
}
```

The second constructor is used for assigning an account as manager. A manager can manage a set of accounts.

```
@Entity
public class DefaultManager implements Manager {

        @OneToOne(targetEntity = DefaultAccount.class)
        private Account managerAccount;

        @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "manager", targetEntity = DefaultAccount.class)
        private Set<Account> accountsToManage = new HashSet<Account>();

        public DefaultManager(Account managerAccount, Set<Account> accountsToManage) {
          this.managerAccount = managerAccount;
          this.accountsToManage.addAll(accountsToManage);
        }
        // Getters
}
```

Will the above relationships work? If not, what's the best alternative to make it working?

Comment: For sure it should work. But if you ask that question, there must be something else involved : why can't you test it ?

Comment: Instead of asking us if that will work, why don't you test it? Why wouldn't it work? Beware of the circular dependency, though. It can be a nightmare to maintain: the manager needs the account to exist, and the account needs the manager to exist

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will work, you can see a SpringTest with hibernate [here](https://gist.github.com/aVolpe/33c9c407a729b101bbaa).

You need a constructor with no arguments to work with JPA, this constructor don't need to be `public`, it can be `protected`.

Also, your entities need a field annotated with `@Id`. If your interfaces provides a `@Id` getter method, you need to put your annotations (`@OneToMany`, etc), in the getters methods of your concrete classes.

If you execute the test, you will see the result:

```
Hibernate: call next value for man_seq
Hibernate: insert into Test25504340$DefaultAccount (manager_id, password, email) values (?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into Test25504340$DefaultAccount (manager_id, password, email) values (?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into Test25504340$DefaultAccount (manager_id, password, email) values (?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into Test25504340$DefaultManager (managerAccount_email, id) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: update Test25504340$DefaultAccount set manager_id=?, password=? where email=?
```

Where:

1. First, get the sequence to insert the manager (I add a attribute `Long id` to `DefaultManager`).
2. It will add the three accounts referencing the Manager (Account#manager -> Manager#id).
3. Insert the Manager
4. Update the references of the `Manager#Account` to target the `Account` one (Manager#manageAccount -> Account#email).

You can change the order of the calls (`persirst` first the manager for example), and the result will be different sequence of inserts with the same final result.